# has anyone opencv framework for Xcode?

Tags: opencv, xcode4.3

I try to create opencv frame work following [this instruction](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/ios_install/ios_install.html)

I don't know why but i got an empty framework. I download a framework separately. I add it correctly....everything is fine. But when i type (for example):

```
#include "opencv/cv.h"
#include "opencv/highgui.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cvNamedWindow("Wi", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
}
```

i got this error: 
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_cvNamedWindow", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Maybe somebody knows how to solve this problem. Or maybe anyone has a correctly framework. Plz, send me a link to download a correct framework. I spent many times with it. Help anybody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some small working iOS example projects compatible with XCode 4.5+ with a recent build of the openCV framework:

http://www.github.com/foundry

See if you can get one of those running (they should not require any modifications), then try drag the openCV framework into your project.

You may have issues if you are running xcode4.3, as most of these were created using Xcode 4.5. But this one:

http://www.github.com/foundry/OpenCVSquaresSL

Has three targets. The SL target uses an openCV framework and build settings designed to run with XCode 4.2 under Snow Leopard, it will probably work if the others don't.

Alternatively - better - upgrade to current XCode (4.6)